# mvc controller returning error res.status is not a function

Tags: javascript, express, model-view-controller

my controller file is giving me an error when using the code below. it says res.status is not a function.

does anyone know what the issue could be? It works if I put the function directly in my routes file.

```
let User = require("../models/user.model");

function getAll (res, req) {
    User.find()
    .then(user => res.json(user))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json("Error: " + err));
}
```

Comment: Flipping the position of the `req` and `res` params will be *very* confusing to anybody dealing with your code.

Comment: that was it, sorry stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase you flipped the parameters for the function, and I assume you're passing them normally where you call this function. It should be `req, res`